# SSMA for MySql is not connecting with SQL server studio. User credential not matched error

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration

I am trying to migrate my existing database kept in MySQL. So I tried it with db migration tool "SQL SERVER Migration Assistance for MySQL". **For MYSQL connection is working fine.** it is in remote PC and connecting perfectly fine.**but when im trying to connect my SQL server studio with SQL server authentication it is saying error in credential whereas my credential is right**. [FYI] *it connects to SQL server studio when opened separately on SQL server studio.* Need help on this. [Error message while trying to login picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dszCV.png)[image: added picture for reference.]

Comment: I hate to say it, but if it's saying the credentials are wrong ,then they are definitely wrong.

Comment: trust me the credentials are right. i can connect to my sql server studio with the same credentials. Even i tried making new username & pass . the problem still exists.

Comment: Then you wouldn't be getting the error. Have you checked the SQL server logs to see what those say?

Comment: This is what the logs says-

[Error: Collector] [10204/15] [2019-12-09 15:45:22]: Error in loading events:ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.5.5-10.4.8-MariaDB]Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'performance_schema'
[Error: Collector] [10204/15] [2019-12-09 15:45:22]: Exception: ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.5.5-10.4.8-MariaDB]Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'performance_schema'
 site: Void HandleError(System.Data.Odbc.OdbcHandle, RetCode)
 source: myodbc8w.dll
 error code: -2146232009

Comment: *"or MYSQL connection is working fine."* -> *"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'performance_schema' "* Those those statements clearly conflict. `root@localhost` is not a SQL Server login, that's a MySQL Login. Those are MySQL errors, not SQL Server errors. Your question says the problem is login into SQL Server, but it isn't the problem at all; the problem is you logging into MySQL. (Also, why are you using `root`? You should be using an appropriate account.)

Comment: After your comment i tried connecting with appropriate account for MYSQL, its still connecting fine . but the SQL server is not . please check the reference pic i just added also Please check the new log -->

"[Error: Generic] [10204/8] [2019-12-09 17:05:31]: Failed to collect metabase data.
[Error: Generic] [10204/8] [2019-12-09 17:05:31]: Exception: Connection to SQL Server failed.
The specified user name or password is not valid."

there are more lines regarding this error. cant fit them all. Can you please suggest me more what to do ? 
TiA for your time.

Comment: Check the SQL Server logs, like i said before; they give more details. The reason it's failing is because the username and password are not correct. I ***assume*** you aren't trying to use an AD account to connect with SQL Authentication, are you..?